# Get timestamp when payload published to topic

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I have kafka-streams application where payload goes through multiple topics, say it starts from topic A->B->c->.. -> L, and ends at L. I have a requirement to find out how much time it took for data to come to Topic L.

from consumer API I have used

```
while (iterator.hasNext()){
    ConsumerRecord<String,String> consumerRecord =iterator.next();
    map.put(consumerRecord.key(),consumerRecord.timestamp()); 
}
```

timestamp is giving me when message got published to topic A, but I wanted to know when message got published to topic L.

**Could anyone help me how to get that value..?**

Comment: The "better" way to get this information would be to add Zipkin kafka interceptors on each producer so that you can trace the time exactly for each request

Comment: @cricket_007 I could not add anything, I want to find that information in performance test

Comment: But if you consume from the `L` topic you should get the timestamp when message sent into `L` topic right? @KarunakarReddyL and how data flows one topic `A` to topic `B` etc..?

Comment: @Deadpool timestamp from topic A and Topic L both are same, they are not getting changed.

Comment: How data is moving from one topic to another topic? @KarunakarReddyL

Comment: @Deadpool to move data from one topic to another using kafka-stream-api,